# cannot update R to 4.2 in conda despite prompt suggesting it's available

Tags: r, conda, mamba

I have an `conda` environment that I use for R. It has R version `4.1.3` installed. I installed it using `mamba install r-base` several months ago.

I now have to update to >=4.2.0, so I tried `mamba install r-base=4.2.0`. I get this very confusing message and it fails to upgrade anything. I tried googling but  found nothing.

```
Could not solve for environment specs
The following package could not be installed
└─ r-base 4.2.0**  is requested and can be installed.
```

It is so confusing.. if I request it and it can be installed, then please go ahead! :)

In the meantime I set up a fresh environment and I can install any r-version I want, but I'd still like to understand what is happening.

Comment: Why force `4.2.0` and not just `4.2`?